# moment-timezone setDefault not behaving as expected

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

Using the following code:

```
console.log(moment().toJSON());
moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Brussels");
console.log(moment().toJSON());
```

I get the following result:

```
2019-05-12T10:39:12.851Z
2019-05-12T10:39:12.863Z
```

However, when I read the documentation of moment-timezone, `setDefault` is supposed to set my default timezone on "Europe/Brussels", so the output should be:

```
2019-05-12T10:39:12.851Z
2019-05-12T11:39:12.863Z
```

Apparently, `setDefault` cannot be used to what I want (which is generating a new date as if I were in the specified timezone), so what would be the best option to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setDefault`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/) works as expected, the issue is the way you are displaying the value of moment instances. [`toJSON()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/) shows time for UTC (See also [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/): *`.toISOString()` returns a timestamp in UTC*):

> When serializing an object to JSON, if there is a `Moment` object, it will be represented as an ISO8601 string, adjusted to UTC.
>
> If instead you would like an ISO8601 string that reflects the moment's `utcOffset()`, then you can modify the `toJSON` function like this:
>
> ```
> moment.fn.toJSON = function() { return this.format(); }
> ```

So you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) instead, here a live sample:

```js
console.log(moment().toJSON());
console.log(moment().format());
moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Brussels");
console.log(moment().toJSON());
console.log(moment().format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```