# Converting moment.js to JSON shows incorrect time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I have a method which sets the created property of my token, like so:

```
const token = new Token();
console.log(moment().toDate());
token.created = moment().toDate().toJSON();
```

There's something I just can't get my head around and it's really confusing me.

The line `console.log(moment().toDate());` prints `Tue Sep 01 2020 14:11:39 GMT+0100` but when I check the property `created` on debugger although it's using the same moment object and methods (except from calling `toJSON()`) it produces a date time which is an hour behind like so: `2020-09-01T13:11:39.179Z`

I store the moment date as a string in the created property because this will be stored in localStorage.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: The reason is that your first date is GMT+1 and the second one is GMT : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time

Comment: Have you tried creating a new `moment` instance with your generated string?

Comment: Instead of this: `moment().toDate().toJSON()`, call this: `moment().toDate().toISOString()` or just format the moment date as ISO 8601 via: `moment().toISOString()`.

Comment: Probably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56098451/4131048) could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The times are the same. Look closely.

One marks the time zone as Z, the other as GMT+1.

Those time zones are 1 hour apart.

You can [specify the time zone](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)

Comment: Why does toJSON product a different timezone? I've tried `moment().utc()` and `moment().utc().toJSON()` but both produce different values

Comment: @KTOV — Because the spec for toJSON says to convert it so the timezone is Z.